# GridView Items color change on select and previously selected item should display other color

Tags: android, android-gridview

My `GridView` has a `Textview` and `Editext` with gray color on selected item.  I need to change that gray color of text and image to some other color(blue),and also get selected row of edittextvalue not other value, and on select of other grid item i need change previously selected items to default grey color and selected one to orange..

i tried with some solutions but  I didn't get my proper output.. please help me with this problem this is what i tried :

```
 convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            final EditText ed = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ed1color);
            text.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rc_button_selected));
            text.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.textcolor));
            ed.setHintTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.textcolor));
            Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.line_selected);
            ed.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, drawable);
            ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    if (!(ed.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))) {
                        onSpinnerItemSelected.onItemSelected(position, ed.getText().toString());
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please be specific about your question .If you have any error or doubt kindly post full logcat or code for attention

Comment: i select first row then selct other row all row change background .previous row not chnage background default color.

Answer (score 0):

When you set a color to a view it will remain until you change it.  What it sounds like you want to do is have different colors for the different states of the view. For that you should use a color list resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/blue"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/blue"/>
    <item android:color="@color/grey"/>
</selector>
```

Then you assign this color list resource to your `textColor` or `background` in your layout xml.

More information can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource